# Expected chromatic number of random subgraph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

Let $G$ be a fixed graph and let $G_p$ be a random subgraph of $G$ where every edge is kept independently with probability $p$. According to [[1]](https://cpb-us-w2.wpmucdn.com/campuspress.yale.edu/dist/0/2827/files/2018/10/2018-Subgraph-chromatic-number-236mktr.pdf) and [[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.02018.pdf) the paper [[3]](https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/%7Enogaa/PDFS/cochrom2.pdf) proves
$$
\mathbb{E}[\chi(G_p)] \geq C_p \chi(G)/\log(|V(G)|),
$$
where $|V(G)|$ is the number of vertices of $G$.
However, to my understanding, [3] only proves that for a graph $G$ with chromatic number $n$, $G$ contains a subgraph with cochromatic number at least $\left( \frac{1}{4} + o(1) \right)\frac{n}{\log_2 n}$.

Comment: Does Lemma 2.2 in [3] or its proof not answer your question?

Comment: I have exactly the same question and I still don't get it... how is z(H) related to it's expected chromantic number?